# "public locale" по-русски?

Tags: перевод

Как лучше всего перевести собирательный термин "public locale"?

> Three actual public locales on Nevsky Prospect are mentioned in Petersburg: the shop Tait Diamonds, confectionary Ballet, and Farce Theater.

В данном случае подразумеваются магазины и театр. Приходит в голову "общественное место" -- кроме этого можно как-то сказать?

Comment: А что за термин "public locale"? Есть "public space" - это формально соответствует понятию "общественное место".

Comment: вот такой термин

Comment: Я имею в виду, он чем-то отличается от "public space"?

Comment: @user4419802 , поддержу Вас. Здесь, вероятно, неточность случилась при разбиении английского текста на части, например: `a public local environment/transport`, `a public local Nature Reserve`, `a public local street lighting`. Но вопрос, несмотря на эту небольшую неточность, смысл всё равно имеет.

Comment: @Avtokod: "public locale" is a legit phrase. It's just a fancy way of saying "public space".

Comment: @Quassnoi `a public local` в таком случае должно переводится как `публично посещаемое место`.

Comment: @Avtokod: "locale" and "local" are different things.

Comment: @Quassnoi, a typo, of course. `a public locale`=`публично посещаемое место`.

Comment: Имеется в виду именно locale, а никакой не local nature reserve etc. Yes, it's a fancy way of saying "public space", maybe a little less ambiguous, because the word space can be either a countable or an uncountable noun in different contexts. Это из статьи о романе "Петербург", написанной по-английски, которую я взялся переводить.

Comment: @biggvsdiccvs: well would you mind to provide some context please then? An excerpt from the article would be best I think.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Gladly. "Three actual public locales on Nevsky Prospect are mentioned in Petersburg: the shop Tait Diamonds, confectionary Ballet, and Farce Theater."

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, в голову приходит `общественное место, публичное место`.

Можно самому оценить, и затем принять решение, какой оборот речи использовать. Для этого удобно использовать *Google Ngram Viewer*

[Вариант 1, единственное число](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%2C+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0)
[Вариант 2, множественное число](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%2C%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%3B%2Cc0)
Попробуйте еще поставить/снять флажок *case-insensitive*.

Имеет смысл использовать тот оборот, частотность которого в наше время выше.

Уточнений от автора OP не последовало, возможен еще один вариант из какого-н. английского контекста:

`a public locale` = `публично посещаемое место`

Comment: Спасибо, тоже вариант, но, надеюсь, еще что-то придет в голову или кто-то подскажет.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё говорят `публичное место`.

[И есть в словарях](http://baldatop.com/dictionary/dmitriev/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

Answer (score 1):

Общественное место имеет какие-то не очень хорошие коннотации в русском, я бы старалась избежать его употребления в значении театры)

Лучше публичное место

Хотя интуиция подсказывает мне, что можно лучше.

Comment: *общественное место* is used in Russian legalese, just like *public space* is in English one.

Comment: i don't say it's not used, i say that it has some unpleasant connotations. 
We use общественное место to talk about toilets, markets, transport stations, but rarely to talk about theatres, restaurants and other cultural places.
By the way we say публичная библиотека instead of общественная библиотека

Comment: `места общественного пользования` (communal areas, public facility)  скорее вот это сочетание слов имеет утилитарный подтекст. Встречается в Городовом Положении (1892) и в Указе Александра II Правительствующему Сенату (1864), *о порядке содержания в исправности улиц, площадей, мостовых, тротуаров, набережных, пристаней, мостов, гатей, общественных садов, бульваров и других мест общественного пользования…*  `Общественное место` *Посредине двора возвышение, место для молитвы ― непременная принадлежность всякого общественного места.* [Верещагин. Из путешествия по Средней Азии (1883)]

Comment: I meant isn't "public space" (not to mention "public locale") primarily some kind of a legal definition? If yes, it would make sense to translate it using a legal definition as well, a term used in codes of law, which *публичное место* is not.

Comment: @KaterinaTort Вот и мне тоже не нравятся коннотации ни "общественного места", ни даже "публичного", и тоже интуиция подсказывает, что можно лучше, но молчит по поводу того, как именно :)

Answer (score 1):

I think *заведение* is the word:

> В "Петербурге" упомянуты три заведения, в действительности существовавшие на Невском: магазин "Бриллианты Тэта", кондитерская Балле и театр "Фарс".

Comment: Спасибо, об этом варианте я тоже подумал, но слово имеет слегка фривольный оттенок -- приходит в голову публичный дом или какой-нибудь трактир.

Comment: @biggvssiccvs: well those mentioned are not exactly Sunday schools either. You could also use some metonymy, like *вывески* or *названия*